# specific part of string

Tags: java, string, substring

How can I get a specific portion of string, let suppose I have a string

```
file:/C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/SWA_Playground.ds
```

and I want to get only

```
C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/
```

The string is dynamic so its not always the same I just want to remove the file word from the beginning and the last portion with .ds extension

I gave it a try as

```
String resourceURI = configModel.eResource().getURI().toString();
//This line gives:  file:/C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/SWA_Playground.ds

String sourceFilePath = resourceURI.substring(6, resourceURI.length()-17)
//This line gives C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/
```

This **resourceURI.length()-17** can create problems because the SWA_Playground.ds is not always same.
How can I just remove the last portion from this string

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understood you, but if you create an instance of File, you can get the directory of it. Is that, what you want?

Comment: You might want to check http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
String sourceFilePath = resourceURI.substring(
        resourceURI.indexOf("/") + 1, resourceURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Basically, create a substring containing everything between the first slash and the last slash.

Output will be:

```
C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

```
String sourceFile = "file:/C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/SWA_Playground.ds";
Sring filePath = sourceFile.substring(6);

File f = new File(filePath);
System.out.println(f.getParent());
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

First you remove the `file:/` prefix, then you have a windows Path and you can create a File instance.

Then you use `getParent()` method to get the folder path, and `getName()` to get the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex:

```
resourceURI.replaceAll("^file:/", "").replaceAll("[^/]*$", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to remove everything before the first slash and after the last one?
Then do this:

```
String resourceURI = configModel.eResource().getURI().toString();
//This line gives:  file:/C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/SWA_Playground.ds

String[] sourceFilePathArray = ressourceURI.split("/");
String sourceFilePath = "";
for (int i = 1; i < sourceFilePathArray.length - 1; i++)
  sourceFilePath = sourceFilePath + sourceFilePathArray[i] + "/";
//sourceFilePath now equals C:/Users/uiqbal/Desktop/IFM_WorkingDirectory/SWA_Playground/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of lastIndexof() method from String class.

```
String resourceURI = configModel.eResource().getURI().toString();
String sourceFilePath = resourceURI.substring(6, resourceURI.lastIndexOf('.'));
```